# Passing a list generated with Javascript to a Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My app is being built with Spring Boot using a MVC pattern, and as template viewer I use Thymeleaf.

I'm generating a dynamic list with Javascript in a form, which I need to collect as a List with the controller.

I have tried to solve it with a @RequestParam, but generating the list with Javascript, as far as I'm concerned, I can't set the Thymeleaf tags.

This is the list:

```
<ul id="addItemList">
   <li class="list-group-item" id="group" name="group" value="Outdoors">Outdoors</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" id="group" name="group" value="Entertainment">Entertainment</li>
</ul>
```

Any indication on which approach I should take, would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved this issue with ajax. I had a button to add an element to the list, which was being made with Javascript. I added a jQuery $.post function to save the item, each time that a new one was added to the list by selecting that button. I didn't find the way to move the whole list from javascript, to the Spring Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Model having a List as property, and pass it as `@ModelAttribute` in your controller.

Comment: Thank you @Touzene Mohamed Wassim,

Comment: I have taken this approach, wrapping the items in a new class, which collets them in a list, that is expected at the @ModelAttribute in my controller. But I still have the problem that I can't read the list generated with Javascript. I've asked a new question, facing the problem with this new focus: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974577/submit-a-list-from-a-form-generated-with-javascript-with-a-spring-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the process:

1. Get the list from controller using ajax
2. Parse the data then generate `li` with the retrieved values and update the html of id `addItemList`